# A sound sensor with Arduino always displays 1023 in the serial monitor

Tags: audio, arduino, android-sensors, arduino-uno

I have connected a sound sensor module which has 3 pins: Vcc, grnd, and output.

The code is pasted below, and I have noticed that the value getting displayed on the serial port is always 1023, no matter the sound.  What is wrong?

```
int sensorPin = A0;
void setup () 
{
pinMode (ledPin, OUTPUT);
Serial.begin (9600);
}
void loop () 
{
sensorValue = analogRead (sensorPin);
Serial.println (sensorValue, DEC);
delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: I have fixed up your grammar a bit and abbreviated the title.

Comment: Give us more details about the sensor name/type and your circuit diagram.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have a simple analog-output sensor module that provides 10bit analog values based on the enviroment volume level. If this assumption is correct, you wired all pins correctly and the recieved value is always out of range or at the maximum, you maybe had to integrate a resistor to get a valid value. Try a small resistor and increase the resistance until you recieve suitable values. Maybe the documentation of your module provides further information.

If you have for example a Adafruit Microphone Amplifier or something similar you should also check the tutorial sites of the manufacture or distributor, which gives you almost always a comprehensive overview about the programming, circuits and possibilities of the module.

The following code from Adafruits Microphone Amplifier exemplifies how you handle sampling rates, convert signals and print out the current volume level.

```c
/****************************************
Example Sound Level Sketch for the 
Adafruit Microphone Amplifier
****************************************/

const int sampleWindow = 50; // Sample window width in mS (50 mS = 20Hz)
unsigned int sample;

void setup() 
{
   Serial.begin(9600);
}


void loop() 
{
   unsigned long startMillis= millis();  // Start of sample window
   unsigned int peakToPeak = 0;   // peak-to-peak level

   unsigned int signalMax = 0;
   unsigned int signalMin = 1024;

   // collect data for 50 mS
   while (millis() - startMillis < sampleWindow)
   {
      sample = analogRead(0);
      if (sample < 1024)  // toss out spurious readings
      {
         if (sample > signalMax)
         {
            signalMax = sample;  // save just the max levels
         }
         else if (sample < signalMin)
         {
            signalMin = sample;  // save just the min levels
         }
      }
   }
   peakToPeak = signalMax - signalMin;  // max - min = peak-peak amplitude
   double volts = (peakToPeak * 3.3) / 1024;  // convert to volts

   Serial.println(volts);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your inputs, As you said I am using analog-output sensor module and there is a small rotating knob connected to the sensor on which we need to rotate to adjust particulat resistance values, now I can see different values in serial monitor out, But my requierment was to measure the frequency of the tone,so is tehre a way to convert theese integers to a frequency values.your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Ah ok, perfect. Maybe your sensor have a LM567/LM567C Tone Decoder or something like that. If you get analog values, you can easily play a reference frequency and map the appearing value to the reference tone (and so on). Otherwise you can check the datasheet of your module to get the relation or google "Arduino sound frequency detection". There are some tutorials for that.

Comment: Or you can filter the output, amplify it, set a threshold and then just measure the distance between the edges. But, in my opinion, you should do at least the first three steps in hardware (a high-pass filter with a cut-off frequency of around 10 Hz, an amplifier and a schmitt trigger) and then you wire this to a digital pin. Then measure the interval between the edges. That's just because usually ADC reads are slow... You can try to reduce the ADC prescaler to get faster readings but.. again, HW is better..

Comment: thank you so much for your inputs fraurgi87,i am trying right away.will try and let you know the result, i may ping you again.

Comment: Hi fraugi87, I  have build high pass filter with 0.1uf and 100k ohms and  coming to opamp, which one will be the best can I go for 741 series opamp or LM324 specifically.Could you guide me on this.

Comment: hi,fraugi87this is my email ID "learnings.mcus@gmail.com",u can send me any circuit examples for reference